# Can I clip mask text over a div in CSS (with or without the help of JS)?

Tags: javascript, css, text, mask

I would like to make a fancy looking button in CSS, where it displays a text overlay for a number on the left (see image below).

Is it possible in CSS (with or without the help of JS) to mask overlay text onto an element, similar to that of the Photoshop 'Clipping Mask'?

EDIT: As always you guys want to know I did some testing, which I did, but did not manage to position the number correctly where the button was on the page, using abosolute and relative position, so I asked here not only so that I could get help, but so that I could archive the answer in a format that can be easily found through Google.  I have tried this.  I want the definitive answer, so that I don't just use a way that 'works', but a way that works well.

[image: Text]

Comment: I don’t see what would need actual clip masking here to begin with, what that image shows can probably be achieved with a bit of positioning and `overflow:hidden` already.

Comment: Can you add the code that you have tried already? Thanks.

Comment: Adding your HTML markup for the buttons would be helpful, as a possible solution would most likely need to take that into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/hc6o7ert/1/)

html:

```
<div class="number">1</div>
```

css:

```
.number{display: inline-block; background-color: #ccc; max-width: 50px; max-height: 50px; width: 50px; height: 50px; font-size: 80px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; line-height: 60%; color: #000; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: middle;}
```

Comment: Awesome, the code can be tweaked to move it around and make it more like the source quite easily, which is great!